# Internet Explorer Caching File Uploads?

Tags: internet-explorer, caching, file-upload

I have a very basic page that includes an `<input type="file">` element.  When I submit the form with a file selected, the server responds with a spreadsheet that gets opened in Excel (a "new window").  The implication of this behavior is that the initial screen and input element are still visible in IE.  If I change the data on disk of the selected file and resubmit the form, Internet Explorer uploads the old contents a second time; my latest changes are not present in the content sent to the server.  If I select the file via the input's Browse... button again, the new file contents are uploaded as expected.  Firefox always sends the file's contents from disk which is the expected/desired behavior.  It seems that Internet Explorer is doing some kind of caching of the uploaded file contents.

Is there any way to disable this "feature" and have IE pull the data from disk each time the form is submitted?

Is there any documentation available on this behavior?  It's the first time I've encountered it and my searches have largely come up empty.

Comment: What if it isn't caching the *upload* (which I've never heard of and would be really weird) but the generated result? Is that result sending the proper caching (or, rather, no-caching) headers?

Comment: @Pekka: The server logs show the browser making a POST request and returning a 200 OK for each upload attempt.  If it were caching the response, I'd expect to either see Internet Explorer skip the request altogether or for the server to return a 304 Not Modified status.

Comment: What technology is being used on server side to handle the upload and process the file? You could log the uploaded files' checksums to see whether the browser is actually sending the wrong file, or whether something else goes wrong on server side

Comment: @Pekka: On the server-side, we're using Spring 3.1.1 with a CommonsMultipartResolver to handle the file upload.  I modified the controller to write out the file stream to disk and recreated the test.  Both the original and modified file are identical on the server's disk.  Again, Firefox does not exhibit this issue which is why I felt it was browser related.

Comment: Strange. I've started a bounty to try and draw more attention to the question. Meanwhile, it might make sense to show some code, both client-side and server side, the relevant snippets that send and store the file. Also what version of IE on what kind of a system, etc.

Comment: I've modified MS' example code for input files here: http://jsfiddle.net/t8kzvwwo/ to better observe the input. If I understand correctly, IE will always report the same file size once you select a file, while firefox will show any changes in its size (as chrome does for me) when hitting the `current file(s)` button?

Comment: @Todd Would you please specify your IE version ?

Comment: I've got this problem, using IE11 on Win7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can test out the conjecture with [live demos posted on MS-Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/1149341/ie10-ie11-ie-can-upload-file-which-is-no-longer-exists).

[...] the bug began with IE10, when FileList and Blob were implemented.
*input.files* is an html5 FileList of file/blob items.
To populate it, IE blobs each filepicker choice. They have a "snapshot state" (W3C term).
They're kept sync'd in case a selected file is updated before submission.
The bug is, IE fails to detect if the file is deleted, renamed, or replaced.
The filepicker snapshot goes stale in that circumstance.

Here is what happens when a file is selected in filepicker, then **renamed** and **edited**, prior to submitting the filepicker selection.  Although a new file (with original filename) has been substituted in its place, the original file (now with *different* *name* and modified text) gets sent in the form.  How is this possible?  It is as though it was tracked via ntfs ObjectID, which is used with [Distributed Link Tracking](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363997(v=vs.85).aspx).  Note carefully in this screenshot, the file *name* does not agree with the file *content*.

[image]

So, it's not a "caching" thing at all. It's a tracking bug.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the `autocomplete` attribute for your `input` tag?

For example

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" />
```

should force **value to be never be reused** as stated in [W3C docs](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/input/text):

> autocomplete = on/ **off**/ default
>
> - on  -  The on state indicates that the value is not particularly sensitive    and the user can expect to be able to rely on his user
>     agent to    remember values he has entered for that control.
> - **off**  -  The off state indicates either that the control's input data is    particularly sensitive (for example the activation code for a
>     nuclear    weapon); or that it is a value that will never be reused
>     (for example    a one-time-key for a bank login) and the user will
>     therefore have to    explicitly enter the data each time, instead of
>     being able to rely on    the UA to prefill the value for him; or that
>     the document provides    its own autocomplete mechanism and does not
>     want the user agent to    provide autocompletion values.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue in IE 10,11 . I am able to fix it using below code

```
var file = $('input[type="file"]');
file.removeAttr('value');
var cloneFile = file.clone();
file.parent().get(0).replaceChild(cloneFile.get(0), file.get(0));
```

If you are getting multiple object for file then use eq(-2) after selector like

```
$('input[type="file"]').eq(-2);
```

Comment me in case any issue .

Answer (score -1):

I have not tried this myself, but you may want to try to use a dummy parameter to the form action and change its value just before every submit action. For example, if you have `<form action="foo.php">`, change this to `<form action="foo.php?dummy=0">`, and then use javascript to change the action part to become e.g. `action="foo.php?dummy=1"` and so on just before each submit.