# why my file is not modified when i re-upload it with IE?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, file-upload, upload

I have a problem when upload a file for the second time with some modifications on internet explorer with javascript, modifications aren't applied, but it works on Firefox. how can i resolve this problem please ?

i tried this META to deactivate cache

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache"/>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1"/>
```

Thank you

Comment: Maybe this thread might help you<br>
[Internet Explorer Caching File Uploads?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29396572/internet-explorer-caching-file-uploads)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to changing the reference to your Js file from:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsfile.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsfile.js?v1"></script>
```

You can increment this each time the Js file is edited and uploaded.
Anything after the ? will be ignored in the src.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys, 
finally onclick="this.value=null" resolve my problem